# @Column annotation in JPA

Tags: java, jpa, orm

I am trying to persist an entity which is mapped with non existing table in the database.
The entity class is

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name = "NEWTABLE")
 public class Account {
       @Id
       @Column(unique=true)
       private int accountNo;
       private String customerName;

       // Respective Getters and Setters
```

The `NEWTABLE` is not present in the database. When I am trying to persist this entity it gives me the following error:

```
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

But if I remove the `unique=true` in the `@Column` annotation, The entity is getting persisted. It will be a great help if you can tell me the reason behind this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If table do not exists then how you are able to persist in Account object into database

Comment: You have already stated the reason behind it : `The 'NEWTABLE' is not present in the database.`

Comment: But if we remove unique= true , it is persisting the same even the NEWTABLE is not present in database.( In persistence.xml if we specify ddl-generation as create-tables then it will create tables if it is not present in the database )

Comment: @Dheepan persisted **where** since the table does not exist?

Comment: @Matteo: It is persisting the data with the table name 'NEWTABLE'.

Comment: @Dheepan if the data is persisted in `NEWTABLE` then `NEWTABLE` exists.

Comment: Did you find an answer ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you first tried without `unique` annotation and then trying to persist the `Account` object with unique=true condition.

If yes, then the reason might be true as it can not update an in-place schema to modify the constraint to `Unique=true`.

If you are using hibernate, Try:

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
```

It will create a schema if one doesn't exist, and attempt to modify an existing one to match the mapping you have defined.

Comment: I have tried with the unique constraint for the first time. Only without unique constraint its working. And even it is accepting unique constraints for other properties. Only when i am using unique constraint for primary key property its giving the error.

Comment: Primary Key have unique constraints by default. You do not need to define them explicitly. May be, this is the reason.

Also, you can try debugging with the 'sql' that the hibernate is generating while persisting the entity